# span4 class is not working with twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, web, html

I'm new to web dev and I'm working with Twitter Bootstrap right now. I am trying to create 3 columns on my page using this code:

```
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
            <div class="span4">
                <h4 class="muted text-center">About me</h4>
                <p>Sample Text1.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn"><i class="icon-user"></i> Text1</a>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <h4 class="muted text-center">About you</h4>
                <p>Sample Text2</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-star icon-white"></i> Text2</a>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                <h4 class="muted text-center">About Us</h4>
                <p>Sample Text3</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info">Text3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I've looked at numerous examples and tested it on my page but they don't seem to work.
This code outputs all the text one above the other and doesn't divide it into columns in the same row.

Do I need to alter the bootstrap.css file in some way? The default one doesn't contain a span4 class or anything.

Comment: which bootstrap version are you using?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming you might have fumbled up with the library you are using for bootstrap and the syntax. (*happened to me a while back*)

As of bootstrap 3.0...`spanX` have been depreciated,instead,`col-xx-##` is used now  where `xx` can be `lg`, `md`, `sm` or `xs` and `#` ranges from 1 to 12

so in above html markup of yours change `<div class="span4">` to `<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">` and it should work

see the demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/q896Q/) 
see  [docs here on how to use it](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

Also, if you are using ver 2.xx of `bs`...i'll suggest you to move to latest 3.0 on which this solution is based!!

Comment: why did they change the systax?  (and not provide fallback!!) The sapnX system is far more intuitive and simple.  At least provide fallback?

Comment: @Jon : i assume, that, they changed because the new layout offers to cover the browser width in much better manner!! :)

Comment: oh crap... changing 100+ views.

Comment: @juFo : do `search+replace` :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you’re using Bootstrap 3 with the classes of Bootstrap 2. Grid class names have changed in the last version, see the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).